# Descargar directorio por ftp en PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Hola estoy intentando descargar un fichero desde mi servidor FTP a mi Windows mediante FTP he probado a hacerlo de diferentes formas establezco la conexión y lee los ficheros pero me da error a copiarlos en mi carpeta. ¿Alguien sabe porque?.

Este es mi codigo:

```js
$dst_dir = 'C:\tmp\images';
$src_dir = '/images';
function ftp_putAll($conn_id, $src_dir, $dst_dir)
{
    $d = dir($src_dir );
    
    while ($file = $d->read()) { // do this for each file in the directory
        
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // to prevent an infinite loop
            print_r($file);
            if (is_dir($src_dir . "\\" . $file)) { // do the following if it is a directory
                
                if (!@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dst_dir . "\\" . $file)) {
                    
                    ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dst_dir . "\\" . $file); // create directories that do not yet exist
                }

                ftp_putAll($conn_id, $src_dir . "\\" . $file, $dst_dir . "\\" . $file); // recursive part
                print_r($src_dir . "\\" . $file, $dst_dir . "\\" . $file);
            } else {

                @ftp_put($conn_id, $dst_dir . "\\" . $file, $src_dir . "\\" . $file, FTP_BINARY);
            }
        }
    }
    $d->close();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: 550 CWD failed "/C:/tmp/Families": directory not found, 450 Internal error creating the directory, 550 Filename invalid.

Comment: El error es claro, te está diciendo que ese directorio no existe. Depura tu código, comprueba valores de variables, verifica que las rutas sean correctas, etc.